# How to append a matrix to itself in ordered way in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, matrix

In python I need to append a matrix to itself so that elements are ordered behind the original element, not matrix behind the original matrix as in np.tile.

Initial matrix I have:

```
start = [[3, 5]
         [8, 6]
         [9, 2]]
```

What I am able to do:

```
import numpy as np
finish = np.tile(start, (2, 1))
finish = [[3, 5]
          [8, 6]
          [9, 2]
          [3, 5]
          [8, 6]
          [9, 2]]
```

What I need:

```
finish = [[3, 5]
          [3, 5]
          [8, 6]
          [8, 6]
          [9, 2]
          [9, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `np.repeat`:

```
np.repeat(start, 2, 0)
```

Output:

```
array([[3, 5],
       [3, 5],
       [8, 6],
       [8, 6],
       [9, 2],
       [9, 2]])
```